# Syntax error near column name in COPY statement in PostgreSQL while importing CSV file into temp table

Tags: csv, syntax, copy

I try to run the following COPY statement:

\COPY tmp_table (first name, last name, e-mail) FROM '/Desktop/persons.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

But I get the following table:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"
LINE 1: COPY  tmp_table ( first name, last name, e-mail ) FROM STDIN...

Any suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You listed three column names: `last name`, `first name`, `e-mail`.

Those are not valid PostgreSQL identifiers.  The first two contain space characters, the last contains a hyphen.

You can use those "special" characters in a name, but you must double-quote the names.  For example:

```
\COPY tmp_table ("first name", "last name", "e-mail") ...
```

See [Identifiers and Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful :)